# Is this class using connection pool feature right now ? - MSSQL 2008 R2 - ASP.net 4.0

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, class, database-connection, connection-pooling

I looked over the web but i could not understand exactly connection pool thing. This is my query executing class. Every query is getting executed by this class.

Thank you.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;

public class DbConnection
{
    public static string srConnectionString = "server=localhost;database=mydb;uid=sa;pwd=mypw;";

    public DbConnection()
    {

    }

    public static DataSet db_Select_Query(string strQuery)
    {
        DataSet dSet = new DataSet();

        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(srConnectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter DA = new SqlDataAdapter(strQuery, connection);
                DA.Fill(dSet);
            }
            return dSet;

        }

        catch (Exception)
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(srConnectionString))
            {
                if (srConnectionString.IndexOf("select Id from tblAspErrors") != -1)
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    strQuery = strQuery.Replace("'", "''");
                    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("insert into tblSqlErrors values ('" + strQuery + "')", connection);
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
            return dSet;
        }
    }

    public static void db_Update_Delete_Query(string strQuery)
    {
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(srConnectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(strQuery, connection);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            strQuery = strQuery.Replace("'", "''");
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(srConnectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("insert into tblSqlErrors values ('" + strQuery + "')", connection);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, connection pools are created per `connection string`. To prevent memory leaks, you should also have a `using` statement around your `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataAdapter` objects as well.

[SQL Server Connection Pooling (ADO.NET)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx)

> A connection pool is created for each unique connection string. When a
>   pool is created, multiple connection objects are created and added to
>   the pool so that the minimum pool size requirement is satisfied.
>   Connections are added to the pool as needed, up to the maximum pool
>   size specified (100 is the default). Connections are released back
>   into the pool when they are closed or disposed.

**Example using statements:**

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(srConnectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    using(SqlDataAdapter DA = new SqlDataAdapter(strQuery, connection))
    {
        DA.Fill(dSet);
    }
}

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(srConnectionString))
{
    if (srConnectionString.IndexOf("select Id from tblAspErrors") != -1)
    {
       connection.Open();
       strQuery = strQuery.Replace("'", "''");
       using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("insert into tblSqlErrors values ('" + strQuery + "')", connection))
       {
          command.ExecuteNonQuery();
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: i am using same string always so i am having 1 pool i suppose. Also i did not get what you mean by using statement around sql command and sql data adapter can you post here ? thank you.

Comment: Updated the answer with example using statements.